# Is there a tool or feature in Visual Studio 2012 to show the xpath of the currently selected web.config setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, web-config

When working on web.config files, is there some way to display the xpath to the currently selected/highlighted setting in Visual Studio 2012, or is there some plugin which can do this.

i.e. something which looks like the xpath thing you get at the bottom of the page when editing HTML/ASPX/CSHTML files shown below: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect for this. I use it all the time for sitecore patch include files.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c06c7b10-41c3-4aa9-8707-570eb9d879e6